# basic CSS issue

Tags: php, html, colors, css, background

Sorry to waste time with this one.  I've been trying to get a page to stack background colors in css, I just wasn't sure how to ask how to do this.  For instance, I'd like to have a white header section which could be 150 pixels in height, then directly beneath that a specific color which might be 20 pixels in height and stretches the width of the page, then repeating this two or three more times with other colors then ending with another large white footer.  Hard to know what to call this.  I dont think I need anything to float, just stack like the white and red in the USA flag.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried anything?

```
<div style="height: 150px; background: #fff;"></div>
<div style="height: 20px; background: red;"></div>
<div style="height: 20px; background: blue;"></div>
<div style="height: 150px; background: #fff;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stretch it out on the page, you can use a position:absolute

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
}
.white {
    background:white;
    height: //height;
}
.blue {
    background:blue;
    height: //height;
}
.red {
    background:red;
    height: //height;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the red white and blue to repeat you could use a background image with one "repetition" of red white and blue and `background: repeat-y`. You could put this in a div and control the height if you don't want it to repeat the entire page height.

```
<div style="height:80%; background:url('flag.png') repeat-y;></div>
```

Maybe something like that?